# How does one create a project to create a Nuget package for Xamarin Forms supporting iOS, Android, and UWP?

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It feels like no one in the world has done this. I can't find any tutorials or help on how to create this. What I'm trying to do is create my own plugin, let's say to add notifications to Xamarin forms, that will work on Android, iOS, and UWP. Every mention of this I see mentions to create a multiplatform library but this is only available for VS for Mac and does NOT include UWP. VS2017 does not include a multiplatform library template. I want it to work like all the other xamarin plugins where you download it from nuget into all your projects and you have access to platform implementations and shared code.

I see other questions on stackoverflow that ask this but they are not answered or have links that are dead and don't work on VS2017.

How can I create a xamarin forms library that can be shared between multiple projects? How can I make this into a nuget package so it is one brainless install and it just works? The more detailed the better as it will help everyone that I saw googling this issue and found no answer.

Remember this is NOT for visual studio Mac like the microsoft tutorials show, but for VS 2017 community edition with the latest updates.

**Edit 1:**

Just to add to some of the comments below, I also tried this plugin that James created and that even doesn't work the way it does in his youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSwH8NrtVCk&feature=youtu.be

The resulting project doesn't have any folders.

Comment: Does .net standard not meet those requirements?

Comment: You can either do the bait-and-switch library approach or the direct replace library approach (review how they do it in Xamarin.Essentials :   https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials) Either way, you are creating a shared (or base lib that is replaced) .NetStd library project and then a platform-based library for each platform you are targeting.

Comment: Have you tried [this tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin)? Or [this one](https://www.bytelion.com/increase-enterprise-net-development-efficiency-by-sharing-code-with-nuget/)?

Comment: @RogerLeblanc The first is for 2015 and the second is for VS for Mac and doesn't support UWP. This looks like what I need but again its for the Mac: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/single-codebase . sushihangover I download a few plugins but they don't seem to have platform implementations when I load the solution so I don't see how I can create a custom control for forms or platform specific code like NSNumber of whatever on iOS.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 Your question referenced "notifications" (i.e. non-visual platform-dependent implementation). If you are looking at visual cross-platform controls that can be consumed by Xamarin.Forms, review : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/ (once you understand "renderers", you can create a multiple platform|project solution that contains the renderer(s) for each platform.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have done custom renderers and custom non visual code already in my app projects. What I'm trying to find out is how to make that in a library like the nuget package where I can just add the dll to another app and get the same functionality. As in if I made something like "SolidSnakeNotifications" which contains shared code interface, and platform specific implementations, how can I add those to new apps I make? Right now I'm copying and pasting all the .cs files into new apps but this won't update all apps on changes. I also updated the question with a video.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 You would not be creating a "single" library, the nuget would have multiple libraries, each with a different "target" (netstd2, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, etc... ). Download a nuget that has targets that includes some of the features that you are trying to replicate to review and unzip it and review the nuget/package structure.

Comment: @SushiHangover I like James Montemagno's plugins and they inspired me to make these to contribute. Taking his vibrate plugin and downloading it https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/VibratePlugin and opening the solution in the src just opens a project with no platform specific implementation. All I see is the cross share definition and interface with no specific code for iOS and Android. I don't see how this can be made into a nuget or even how this is magically giving iOS and Android the ability to vibrate. On github I see the implementation but not in visual studio.

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 In that example, it is using the "TargetFramework" approach to produce multiple libraries from one "project", look at the lines around https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/VibratePlugin/blob/master/src/Vibrate.Plugin/Vibrate.Plugin.csproj#L52 Each target includes platform-dependent code and on line (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/VibratePlugin/blob/master/src/Vibrate.Plugin/Vibrate.Plugin.csproj#L4) you can see all the targets that this project is targeting. When compiled it will produce one library for the currently selected target (in the VS IDE)

Comment: @SolidSnake4444 When compiling for all targets (i.e. building a Nuget), all targets are compiled (one-by-one), with each target, in this case, producing a single library (some platform dependent and of course the NetStd2.0 one is not)

Comment: I am able to do using this [Xamarin Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-packages-for-xamarin) hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly what MvvmCross, ReactiveUI and other frameworks do. So claiming no one in the world has done this is some kind of wild imagination.

One way to do it is to create a Multi-Target library, just be aware that Visual Studio for Mac doesn't like those projects yet and you will have issues creating and developing such a library there. However, if you only develop on Windows Visual Studio 2017 and newer supports these kind of projects very well.

You can start off by creating a .NET Standard library in VS, which will give you a project with a single .cs file containing Class1, go a head and remove that.

If you edit the .csproj file you will see a `PropertyGroup` in the top of the file containing a property called `TargetFramework`. Change that to `TargetFrameworks` and list all the desired frameworks you want to target:

```
<PropertyGroup
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;Xamarin.iOS10;MonoAndroid81;uap10.0.16299</TargetFrameworks>
```

If you want easy support in Multi-Target libraries, I advise you to switch to MSBuildSDKExtras for your project SDK, as it will handle a lot of the quirks that comes with targeting Xamarin platforms. It will add necessary properties to your project to make all of this work.

So first line of the .csproj file will have to look like:

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/1.6.68">
```

Now you need to specify in which folders your platform specific code is in. What I usually do is to create a `platforms` folder with `android`, `ios` and `uap` folders and consider the rest of the code platform independent and residing in `common`.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="platforms\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="platforms\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard')) ">
    <Compile Include="platforms\common\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.iOS')) ">
    <Compile Include="platforms\ios\**\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="platforms\common\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid')) ">
    <Compile Include="platforms\android\**\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="platforms\common\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('uap')) ">
    <Compile Include="platforms\uap\**\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="platforms\common\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To nicely create NuGet packages from this Multi-Target library, I usually add a `Directory.build.props` file in the root of the solution where I specify properties for the Packages:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Company>Cheesebaron</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright © Cheesebaron</Copyright>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/cheeesebaron/cool-stuff</RepositoryUrl>
    <Authors>Cheesebaron</Authors>
    <Owners>Cheesebaron</Owners>
    <PackageReleaseNotes />
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>git</RepositoryType>
    <Product>$(AssemblyName) ($(TargetFramework))</Product>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>

    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591;1701;1702;1705;VSX1000;NU1603</NoWarn>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' and '$(IsTestProject)' != 'true'">true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>

    <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>

    <IsTestProject>$(MSBuildProjectName.Contains('UnitTests'))</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Also I add a `Directory.build.targets` file defining the constants for the different platforms:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NETSTANDARD;PORTABLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.iOS'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;UIKIT;COCOA;IOS</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;ANDROID</DefineConstants>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

If you are targeting Android, you will probably also need to add:

```
<None Include="Resources\*.cs" />
<Compile Remove="Resources\*.cs" />
```

To the first `ItemGroup` in your .csproj file and add something like:

```
<AndroidResource Include="Resources\**\*.xml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:UpdateAndroidResources" />
<AndroidResource Include="Resources\**\*.axml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:UpdateAndroidResources" />
```

To the Android `ItemGroup` to properly update Android Resources.

Adding files in Visual Studio can be a bit tricky and it will often add them in the wrong place for the first couple of files until you have something in all of the platform specific folders. But you shouldn't need anything else in the .csproj file as long as the files are placed correctly in the structure we've defined.

You can see examples of Multi-Target libraries here:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/MvvmCross.csproj
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/Directory.build.props
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/Directory.build.targets

And similarly for ReactiveUI:

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveUI.csproj

As of now it is not super easy to get started, but is fine to work with.
Alternatives to this are .NET Standard libraries and platform specific libraries adding the Bait-and-switch pattern.

Comment: Would this allow you to type code in the iOS folder and have code completion for iOS specific classes and then move to the Android folder and get Android specific code completion? I've heard the term bait and switch pattern before, do you have an example of that? Is multiplatform target libraries the best of the three you mentioned?

Comment: Yep. There will be a drop down box top left in your editor where you can switch target framework too.

Comment: I've tried the above but I don't see any platform specific classes such as iOS NSNumber or have autocomplete. I copied and pasted everything above except the nuget directory build to start. I left the ** in the item groups assuming it was a catch all. In VS at the top by the play run button, if I hit the arrow on the right I can select what framework I want. If I switch to iOs and then open the cs file in the iOS folder, I cannot access Xamarin.iOS. No autocomplete shows xamarin as an option. Under depencies I do see Xamarin.iOS. How can I access classes like NSNumber?

Comment: Let me cook up a small example for you, because you are clearly doing it wrong, which unfortunately with the tooling we have got now is very easy to do.

Comment: I've added a more complete sample in this repo: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MultiTargetSample

Comment: That project sample worked for me. I can open up each class and have the autocomplete to the classes on that platform. My final two questions based on that sample is that all your sample ap projects seem to reference the netstandard folder dll version, is that supposed to be the case as opposed to the iOS version pointing to the one in the iOS folder? Second question is how do I make the nuget package from this? Tutorials Ive seen before say right click project and then make nuget package but I don't see that option.

Comment: So as you may notice in the `Directory.build.props` there is a property called `GeneratePackageOnBuild`. In the example it is set to true only when building the Release configuration. In that case, you should notice a package being output in the bin folder for the multi-target library. As for the other question. The App projects reference the library project itself. Where do you see "seem to reference the netstandard folder dll version"?

Comment: I built in release and see the nuget package. For the "where do I see the reference" question,if I open a SampleApp (UAP), then expand references and right click on MultiTargetLib and select properties, the path there leads to the debug folder and then netstandard folder. I think this might just be the IDE though as I see you just referenced the project in the reference window. I think this will be a good start for me. Thank you for the sample. If you did anything different for the sample than your answer I would update the answer for any new viewers. I've marked this as accepted.