# Create multi-target Xamarin.Forms NuGet package

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, class-library, multitargeting

I'm trying to build a single NuGet package that can be installed in Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.UWP and Xamarin.Forms (.NET Standard) projects. I can't use .NET Standard since I need to have a custom `Activity` for my Android project, custom `AppDelegate` for my iOS project, and a custom MainPage for my UWP project. In the initiators I want to use the `ServiceCollection` as DI provider.

In the docs they still mention the [Portable Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=windows) (explicitly mentioned legacy, doesn't exist anymore in VS), or [Manually Creating Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-manual) (can't figure out what to do here), and then you also have websites mentioning the `Xamarin.Forms Plugin`, which also doesn't exist anymore.

I already made a solution with all 4 projects, but I can't figure out how I can create a single NuGet package for all 4 projects (all 3 target platforms).

Does anyone have an idea how we can build a multi-target NuGet package containing code for Android, iOS, and UWP, just like the [Xamarin.Forms NuGet package](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms)?

I've also seen discussions like this: [How does one create a project to create a Nuget package for Xamarin Forms supporting iOS, Android, and UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291602/how-does-one-create-a-project-to-create-a-nuget-package-for-xamarin-forms-suppor), but I'm not sure if this is still relevant, since the `build.props` and `build.targets` no longer exist in the MvvmCross repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've pushed a working version to https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.MVVM

csproj-file

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.0.41">

  <!-- You must have the Android 8.0 SDK installed through the Android SDK manager -->

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>MintPlayer.MVVM</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>MintPlayer.MVVM</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;Xamarin.iOS10;MonoAndroid80;uap10.0.16299</TargetFrameworks>
    <_WriteTelemetryProperties>false</_WriteTelemetryProperties>
    <Authors>Pieterjan De Clippel</Authors>
    <Company>MintPlayer</Company>
    <Product>MintPlayer.MVVM</Product>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>snupkg</SymbolPackageFormat>
    <Description>This package allows you to implement ViewModel Navigation and Dependency Injection in a Xamarin.Forms project</Description>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Copyright />
    <PackageLicenseExpression>Apache-2.0</PackageLicenseExpression>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.MVVM</PackageProjectUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.MVVM</RepositoryUrl>
    <PackageTags>Xamarin.Forms, Viewmodel navigation, Dependency Injection</PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>This package is still under construction</PackageReleaseNotes>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Platforms\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="Platforms\**\*.cs" />
    <None Include="Resources\*.cs" />
    <Compile Remove="Resources\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('uap')) ">
    <Compile Include="Platforms\UAP\**\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Platforms\Common\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard')) ">
    <Compile Include="Platforms\Common\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.iOS')) ">
    <Compile Include="Platforms\iOS\**\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Platforms\Common\**\*.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" $(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid')) ">
    <Compile Include="Platforms\Android\**\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Platforms\Common\**\*.cs" />
    
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\**\*.xml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:UpdateAndroidResources" />
    <AndroidResource Include="Resources\**\*.axml" SubType="Designer" Generator="MSBuild:UpdateAndroidResources" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Platforms\Common\MintPlayerMvvmExtensions.cs" />
    <None Remove="Platforms\Common\NavigationService.cs" />
    <None Remove="Platforms\Common\Platform.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.6" />

    <!--<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.5.0.495" />-->
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="3.1.0.697729" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Directory.build.props

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Company>MintPlayer</Company>
    <Copyright>Copyright © MintPlayer</Copyright>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.MVVM</RepositoryUrl>
    <Authors>Pieterjan De Clippel</Authors>
    <Owners>MintPlayer</Owners>
    <PackageReleaseNotes />
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>false</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>git</RepositoryType>
    <Product>$(AssemblyName) ($(TargetFramework))</Product>
    <NeutralLanguage>en</NeutralLanguage>
    
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591;1701;1702;1705;VSX1000;NU1603</NoWarn>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' and '$(IsTestProject)' != 'true'">true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    
    <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
    
    <IsTestProject>$(MSBuildProjectName.Contains('UnitTests'))</IsTestProject>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Directory.build.targets

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('netstandard'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NETSTANDARD;PORTABLE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('Xamarin.iOS'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;UIKIT;COCOA;IOS</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('MonoAndroid'))">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);MONO;ANDROID</DefineConstants>
    <MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoAndroidResourcePrefix>
    <AndroidResgenClass>Resource</AndroidResgenClass>
    <AndroidResgenFile>Resources\Resource.designer.cs</AndroidResgenFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

You must add the following to your `.sln` file

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{7004E39A-BAF2-4F2F-B505-CC3DEC393CB6}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        Directory.build.props = Directory.build.props
        Directory.build.targets = Directory.build.targets
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Answer (score 1):

On starting point is https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras

A year ago, I made a sample (and collected some documentation and references), which might be inspiring for this subject: https://github.com/ZeProgFactory/MSBuildSdkExtrasTest

and https://github.com/ZeProgFactory/MediaPlayer is using it

And definitively, you should look at the repositories of James Montemagno's components at https://github.com/jamesmontemagno

With these references you should be able to start. But all of these had a mayor difference with your approach:

- they are using one project (via MSBuildSdkExtras),
- which is builded for all the platforms
- and, finally, the binaries are assembled in one NuGet.

Perhaps you may take only this last step. Anyway, this approach is at least an option.
Hope this helps …

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Comment: It's really a lot to process at once. I'm also looking at the [InAppBillingPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/InAppBillingPlugin) but it's immediately a huge project and I don't have any lead where to start.

Comment: Thanks. I finally pulled it off