# It’s possible convert Xamarin Forms app to Nuget package?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, nuget-package

I developed Xamarin Forms app with Android and iOS platforms. I would like to know if it’s possible convert this app in a nuget package and run my app in other app.
Of course it would be a nuget package per platform.
I know that importing one project into another can, but I want to protect code. I also don't know if nuget packages can have UI.

Can you help me??

many thanks!!

Comment: Xamarin Forms itself is a nuget package, so of course you can have UI in one.  But you can't just magically package an existing app as a nuget library - it really needs to be written as a library, not an app, and then packaged as nuget.

Comment: Yes, that's some third-part library do. Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291602/how-does-one-create-a-project-to-create-a-nuget-package-for-xamarin-forms-suppor) and [these documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/?tabs=macos) may help.

Comment: Thanks! There are not many examples of this but it is a starting point. I start to try it